# Accessing privacy settings of Facebook post (open graph action)

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, visibility, facebook-opengraph, privacy

My app has the publish-permission:"publish_actions" and the read-permissions: "public_profile", "email", "user_posts".
After posting an open graph action i want to find out what visibility setting the post has (private, friends, public).
I am calling the following method (Swift)

```
let request2 = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "postid", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
    request2.startWithCompletionHandler(...)
```

**EDIT:**

i receive the following response:

```
{
    data =     {
        location =         {
            id = 00000000000;
            title = "Sample title";
            type = "my_namespace:location";
        };
    };
    "end_time" = "2016-02-01T09:35:35+0000";
    id = postid;
    "start_time" = "2016-02-01T09:35:35+0000";
    type = "my_namespace:check_in";
}
```

So there does not seem to be a privacy information i get from the post.
Is there a way to get it? According to [developers/facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post) there should be a privacy field.

Answer (score 0):

So this took me forever to find out. Here is the solution:
When you post an Open Graph Story you get an id as response. This id alone however will not be sufficient when retriving info about it. You need to append the facebook user id at the beginning of the received postid. So the correct id is "userid_opengraphpostid" (underscore needed). The you can make the request with the parameter ["fields":"privacy"] (swift, ios).